# Design Problem: Breaking down a monolith web application

Tags: design, web-applications

Problem Description: We have a big monolith app containing UI components **A**,**B**,**C**,**D**. You can think of a component as a page for now. Component A & B share a sub-component called **SHARED**. Now both A & B are planing to move out of the big monolith app. The challenge here is to have same look and feel for sub-component **SHARED** in both **A** & **B** at all times.

My Solution: Publish the sub-component as module. Both **A** & **B** import it and use it. The problem here is whenever a new version of sub-component gets published, both **A** & **B** would need a release. Releasing both A & B at the same time won't be straight forward. This needs co-ordination between the teams that maintain A & B respectively. There may be a possibility when A got released but B had to rollback because of some other breaking change. This scenario violates our requirement of consistent look and feel for the sub-component across A & B at all times. There would be other similar scenarios too. How should we handle this?

Is there a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: **TL;DR:** Are you really thinking about this the right way?

It sounds to me like your module **SHARED** is not really modularized. If it truly was then breaking changes would be an extremely rare occurrence. Breaking changes would also typically be a major release (i.e. version 1.2.4 to version 2.0.0) which means that both teams are expected to put in the work to verify the solution. Also, if you've modularized **SHARED** then you should be using a package management system to distribute it and manage versions, making it a package update, not a full release of an entire application.

Comment: It's a web app. Packages would be node modules. Upgrading SHARED node module would require deployment.

Comment: I fail to see the relevance of this fact.

Comment: So SHARED ends up being a service as well. Problem solved

Comment: @ThomasJunk This is what I'm also thinking. SHARED service response would be a independent js/html bundle which can be consumed by both  A & B. By independent I mean, independent of the frameworks used by A & B.

Answer (score -1):

hi wont it be better if in place of integrating the subcomponent both A & B refer it as a seprate component C? I mean structural integrity so and A and B rather than processing data from C the processing is done in C itself this will make C changes independent of both A & B and as long as we have dependency we cant make sure both A & B will be at same level /